# Bald subgroups in forest plot generated by forester R package

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I would like the labels of the subgroups to be bald in the forest plot generated by the packager `forester` in `R`. There is no such argument in the package itself.

Here is an example from the package itself:

```
library(forester)

table <- readxl::read_excel(system.file("extdata", "example_figure_data.xlsx", package = "forester"))

# indent the subgroup if there is a number in the placebo column
table$Subgroup <- ifelse(is.na(table$Placebo), 
                         table$Subgroup,
                         paste0("   ", table$Subgroup))

# remove indent of the first row
table$Subgroup[1] <- "All Patients"

# use forester to create the table with forest plot
forester(left_side_data = table[,1:3],
           estimate = table$Estimate,
           ci_low = table$`CI low`,
           ci_high = table$`CI high`,
           display = T,
           xlim = c(-100, 25))
```